# adview in the top and in the bottom of a webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a webview and I'd like to place a adview in the top and in the bottom of the page:

> adview
>
> webview
>
> adview

I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

the adview in the top appears to be correct, but in the bottom the banner is not showing.
any ideas?

Comment: Use layout_weight to webview set to 1 & change height to 0dp.

Answer (score 2):

Your WebView is covering the bottom adview.
In WebView tag,

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

change it to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and if you still want to cover the whole page, then you need to atleast leave some space for adview

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
```

Now here is the tough part, on testing you will get an ad of 90dp but in realtime, you never know what size it will be and hence the name smart banner (the height can vary)

Comment: Did you find any solution aligning the view based on the height of the smart banner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `layout_weight` attribute as below

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using constraint layout as follows

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bottom banner is not showing because you set height of webview fill_parent

```
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

To achieve this layout you can use `weight` attribute.

Like below:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:id="@+id/adView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1/1">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope its work for you